# Connect a Digital Camera using .Net WPF Like WebCam

Tags: c#, .net, camera

I want to build a Project where I can Use a Digital Camera Via my WPF Software to Capture Photos.
So I just want to Know Is there a Dll or Code Where i Can Connect my digital Camera as we use a Web Cam to Click a Picture
Using .Net,WPF,C#

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it really depends on your camera model, some specific camera do has some driver to turn it into a WebCam, so what you need to do is just code as you are using WebCam, however, if the camera do not have such a driver software, you need to go ahead code in hardware level to really make it happen like you are coding the specific driver for it, and different camera may need different driver which I bet you don't want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is very vendor-specific and I'd venture a guess that few to no digital cameras support remote operation via USB (or whatever the communication tech is).  And even then you'll only be able to target specific Vendor / Model cameras.  Using the built-in webcam is the most generalized way to snap photos programmatically.

Try Googling "programmatically control digital camera" ... that'll help you find a little more info.